# dollar sign in associative array Index

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics API in PHP. I am fetching JSON data which I am converting into Associative Array by using Json_decode however when try to access attribute **dxp$dimension**, it gives error since it evals $dimension as a separate variable.

How do I evaluate whole thing as an Index for fetching data?

Answer (score 3):

```
$array['dxp$dimension']
```

Comment: +1 See this [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for an explanation on the difference between double and single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single tick instead of double:

```
$array['variable$name'];
```